# C# - Finding a string between two strings

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

I have a `string` that looks like this: `Value->Value2->Value3->ImportantValue->val`.

I would like to extract `ImportantValue`. I have read other posts concerning this question but none of them works for me. I tried this:

```
int pFrom = path.IndexOf("->") + "->".Length;
int pTo = path.LastIndexOf("->val");
String result = path.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
```

It returns `Value2->Value3->ImportantValue->val` because it gives out the string between the first `->` and `->val`. Any ideas on how I would change the above code so that it returns `ImportantValue`? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to specify that `ImportantValue` is always different. The entire string also changes, meaning it will have more three `Values`. But the `ImportantValue` is always the second to last element so I will mark the answer from Paul Kertscher as the right one and upvote the other similar answers.

Comment: Does "ImportantValue" have some kind of specific formatting or pattern that you are looking for? Maybe it will always be the same value?

Comment: Is it always the third one?

Comment: Could you give us a realistic string to work with? It might be easier to identify the important value rather than using the '->' marker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ImportantValue` is always the second to last element, you could do the following

```cs
var stringParts = path.Split(new[]{ "->" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if(stringParts.Length >= 2)
{
    var importantValue = stringParts[stringParts.Length - 2];
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Input did not match the expected value");
}
```

You could also use `IEnumerable` extensions

```
var importantValue = path.Split(new[]{ "->" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                         .Reverse() // reverse the enumerable
                         .Skip(1)   // discard "val"
                         .First();  // return the "ImportantValue"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Provided that** the string has always the same format, you could use just the Split method, and fetch the previous from the last element of the array returned from Split.

```
var values = path.Split(new []{"->"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var importantValue = values[values.Length-2];
```

Pls check [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RyfSSG)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) method for that and access a second item from the end

```cs
var str = "Value->Value2->Value3->ImportantValue->val";
var items = str.Split(new []{"->"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var importantValue = items[items.Length - 2];
```

C# 8 introduced an new approach for indices, so you can use `var importantValue = items[^2];` syntax as well

You also may check a length of resulting array, that it has at least two elements

Comment: This is the same answer as @Christos

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use string.split with ">" as your char array and get the array. Once you get the array you should be able to iterate the array and get the required value

Answer (score 0):

When important value is the `2nd` from the **end**, `LastIndexOf` instead of `IndexOf` is a quite natural choice; please, note that since we seach *from the end*, it's `pTo` which we compute *first*.

```
  string path = "Value->Value2->Value3->ImportantValue->val";

  string delimiter = "->";

  int pTo   = path.LastIndexOf(delimiter);
  int pFrom = pTo >= 0 ? path.LastIndexOf(delimiter, pTo) + delimiter.Length : -1;

  // Either important value or null
  string result = pFrom >= 0 
    ? path.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom) 
    : null; // or throw exception here
```